# Как поменять цвет SVG

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="partner-page-top">
    <div class="ppt-left">
        <a href="#" class="back-btn">
            {{>svg/svgIntBack}}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

С помощью `fill` и `stroke` ничего не меняется, т.к они уже заданы в `{{>svg/svgIntBack}}`

Comment: Напишите подробнее что у вас в переменной содержится и что значит "уже заданы"? Ведь задавать можно по-разному, например в подключенном к документу CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Удалите с вашего svg-файла любое явное задавание цвета и повесьте на тег `path` атрибут `fill="currentColor"`. После этого вы сможете задавать цвет иконки через стили:

```
svg {
  color: red;
}
```